# Why my program stops when i try to give values in an array of a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I need to create a graph and in its nodes to store a couple of variables. For this purpose I thought of creating a struct with an array and an integer. Then to create a 2-d array that will hold all of the nodes that I created and a second one to hold the connections between the nodes. My problem is that when I try to initialize my nodes-array the program stops working. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 struct node {
               int KEYS_UNLOCKED[43];
               int points_given;
        };


struct node **NODE_MAT;
NODE_MAT = malloc(doors*sizeof(struct node *) * sizeof(struct node));
for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
    NODE_MAT = malloc(doors*sizeof(struct node *) * sizeof(struct node));

for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<doors; j++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<43; k++)
                NODE_MAT[i][j].KEYS_UNLOCKED[k] = 0;
            NODE_MAT[i][j].points_given = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you have no instance of your struct.

Comment: Thanks i didn't see that!

Comment: Still not working though

Comment: Why - `NODE_MAT = malloc(doors*sizeof(int));` ? It should be - `NODE_MAT = malloc(doors*sizeof(struct node *) * sizeof(struct node));`. Also, what's with that `typedef`?

Comment: Still nothing,the typedef was a "desperate" change in case it works,not that it would but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct 
{
  int KEYS_UNLOCKED[43];
  int points_given;
}node ;

node **NODE_MAT;

NODE_MAT = (node **)malloc(doors*sizeof(node *)); 
for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
   NODE_MAT[i] = (node *)malloc(doors*sizeof(node));


for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<doors; j++)
  {
    for (k=0; k<43; k++)
        NODE_MAT[i][j].KEYS_UNLOCKED[k] = 0;
    NODE_MAT[i][j].points_given = 0;
  }
}

// At end don't forget to free memory !
for(i = 0; i < doors; i++)
    free(NODE_MAT[i]);
free(NODE_MAT);
```

Comment: Works 4 out of  5 (literally... I don't know why it does that).
In the end I only had `free (NODE_MAT);` , I didn't know that I had to do the for loop before.

Comment: @AlexisS. It shouldn't, it will use an entire `doors X doors` matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct node
{
    int KEYS_UNLOCKED[43];
    int points_given;
};

struct node **NODE_MAT;
NODE_MAT = malloc(doors*doors*sizeof(struct node *)); 

for(i=0; i<doors*doors; i++)
                     NODE_MAT[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
for(i=0; i<doors; i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<doors; j++)
  {
    for (k=0; k<43; k++)
        NODE_MAT[i*doors+j]->KEYS_UNLOCKED[k] = 0;
    NODE_MAT[i*doors+j]->points_given = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! But does your form mean that I have to act as NODE_MAT is 1-d array?